# Don't like the new Dark Theme color pallette

Tags: discussion

I recently noticed that the dark theme colors changed. The green color for question answers with one answer selected as the correct answer is noticebly lighter/less saturated—and frankly, harder to read on the dark theme. The same is true of the red dot on the review queue.

All in all, the new theme colors are a *HUGE* step backward from the previous theme. Ugh, even in High Contrast mode, the colors are too light for a dark theme. Meanwhile, the light theme, which blinds me, has awesome contrasting colors that are nice and dark for the green color for answered questions. The old addage comes to mind: "If it ain't broke, don't fix it."

Comment: Well, feedback goes here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393939/new-colors-launched . There are three pages of it already currently.